# In hybrid ice screws, how are the tip and body joined?

Tags: climbing-anchors, ice-screws

Most ice screws are manufactured from a single material - mostly steel. In recent years, lighter ice screws with an aluminum body and a steel tip have made their appearance in the market:

[image: https://www.petzl.com/INT/EN/Sport/Anchors/LASER-SPEED-LIGHT]
[image: https://www.blackdiamondequipment.com/en_US/product/ultralight-ice-screw/]

How are the steel tip and aluminum body joined to ensure they hold well together? Are they glued or pressed into each other to fit? The CTE of Aluminum is double the one of steel, and the temperature range they see is large, so I do not think it is so easy to join them reliably without fasteners.

Comment: From this broken image and description maybe threaded plus glue? https://www.mountainproject.com/forum/topic/120214019/bd-ultralight-ice-screws-steel-bit-separating-from-aluminum-screw-tube

Comment: @noah Good catch. I've looked at the images in the forum thread and see no threads on the screw, so it is probably just a press fit with the "single tooth" to take the torsional moment

Comment: _Aluminium_ body, and not titanium alloy?  The latter is more usual where I'm from.

Comment: @TobySpeight Where are you from? The ones from Petzl and Black Diamond have an aluminium body